# Why are there 2 silent mode icons on this phone?

Tags: android-versions

[image]

Why does this phone have 2 silent mode icons ??

Comment: I believe the other on is"Do not Disturb Icon"

Answer (score 0):

The left one (a circle with a dash) is the icon for DND mode (Do Not Disturb), while the right one is in fact "silent incoming call".

Comment: Never was this feature on this phone b4. What does silent incoming call mean exactly????? Second phone line on one phone ??

Comment: Or does it mean certain calls are blocked??